# Having trouble joining the rigify with rig bone and hair rig mirrors

Tags: animation, rigging, physics, rigify

I need your help. how do I join rigify? I have tried that and it messed up. see the picture below.

[image]

see the red circle. that's a hair bone. and an orange one that's rigify.

Then the second picture, when I join the hair bone to  rigify, it's kind of torn up.
[image]

Also, I have a problem with the hair rig mirror. I'm kind of confused and I lost track of time about what to do first, should I try to apply a mirror on both hairs first, then rig it,  then join the rigify?  or segregate each hair or something? I'd lost my mind when come to joining and mirror.

Make sure you add a picture/gif explanation to help me better understand and show how you make it so I can comprehend how to make it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the rig you tried to join got rotated 90 degreees on Z axis: before joining, the two rigs should have all transform applied (loc 000, rot 000, scale 111), use Ctrl A to apply all transforms. Then create the mirrored bone chain, check if all new bones have an unique name, then select both rigs (rigify should be last selected and brighter yellow) and press Ctrl J. Then in edit mode set an appropriate parenting of the new bones toward a Rigify parent bone (could be head control bone or spine.006 bone).